prevent initial suspend of boost awaitable
I have a function that returns a boost::asio::awaitable that takes a large message object as argument to write a serialized string to a socket. Recently I was reading that a coroutine function will always suspend on entry and has the potential to create dangling references. I also read that you can prevent it from suspending which the author called a hot start. Is there a way to make boost::asio::awaitable not suspend initially so I can pass by reference safely before the first co_await?
article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210331-00/?p=105028

Asio has chosen the initial suspend approach. I think you can use Boost Cobalt which does integrate with Asio.

what is boost cobalt? (thanks for the advice btw)

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/libs/cobalt/doc/html/index.html#overview - new in 1.84.0 https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_84_0.html

If the scope that denotes the lifetime of the message object is in a coroutine, and you co_await the sending coroutine within that scope, then you won't have a dangling reference.
If that isn't the case, then you will have to wrap the message sending coroutine in a coroutine with a different return type than boost::asio::awaitable, where  the wrapping coroutine doesn't suspend at entry, and you copy or move the message into a local variable before co_awaiting the inner coroutine.
